# SQL syntax around BIGINT inside SUM

Tags: sql, postgresql

Below query gives me syntax error from PSequel `ERROR: syntax error at or near ","`

```
SELECT
  bank_transfers.date as day,
  CAST(SUM(bank_transfers.amount_cents) as BIGINT) as gross_value
FROM bank_transfers
JOIN customers on customers.id = bank_transfers.customer_id
WHERE customers.id = 1
AND bank_transfers.date < Thu, 26 Nov 2020
AND bank_transfers.date >= Wed, 26 Aug 2020
GROUP BY day
```

So I've check it by [everysql validator](https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/) and received an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; it seems the error is around: 'BIGINT) AS gross_value FROM bank_transfers JOIN customers ON customers.id = ' at line 3

What am I missed?

Comment: Your dates need to be in the correct format

Comment: I'd do `SUM(CAST(bank_transfers.amount_cents as BIGINT))`, to avoid overflow in SUM.

Comment: That validator is only for MySQL ("EverSQL Validator is a free online syntax checker for MySQL SQL statements") not for Postgres

Comment: You don't really need the cast to begin with. `sum()` will automatically deal with that

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If I don't need cast what will be syntax for sum? I'm getting an error after deletion

Comment: `SUM(bank_transfers.amount_cents) as gross_value` but as others have mentioned your date constants are wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix the date format:

```
SELECT
  bank_transfers.date as day,
  CAST(SUM(bank_transfers.amount_cents) as BIGINT) as gross_value
FROM bank_transfers
JOIN customers on customers.id = bank_transfers.customer_id
WHERE customers.id = 1
AND bank_transfers.date < '2020-11-26'
AND bank_transfers.date >= '2020-08-26'
GROUP BY day
```